# Wiring an IR blaster+receiver board

Tags: ir

I've salvaged this small IR blaster+receiver board from an old computer toy:

[image: board front]
[image: board back]

As you can see the board was connected to the main unit via a 4-wire cable labelled like this:

- LED (yellow) (I guess this is the IR LED/blaster)
- IR (white) (I guess this is the IR receiver)
- VCC (red)
- GND (black)

I'd like to use this board with an [Arduino library like IRremote](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/universal-ir-remote-control-using-arduino-android), but I am not sure about the VCC voltage and whether I need to add more components on the Arduino side.

UPDATE:
I've checked the LED with a multimeter and indeed it is a visible bicolor LED, so there is no IR blaster in this board. At this point, is there any good reason to keep the IR receiver on the board rather than just cutting it and reusing as a standalone component?

Comment: The receiver (the 3 pin part inside the metal case) appears to be a common IR receiver.  It is likely you can pull that part and use it as the IR receiver in many of the Arduino examples found on line.  The LED (3 pin part made up of only plastic???) is unexpected.  Most of the time IR LED are only 2 pin devices.  As IR LED are inexpensive it might be better to simply buy a new IR LED.

Comment: it should be ready to go, that the same stuff you find on new modules

Comment: I think the led on the left is just a (visible) indicator led. Since it's a three pin package, it's probably a bi-color one. Could you add a photo of the board, where the wires aren't obscuring part of the PCB? The MELF-diode is puzzling to me, as I was expecting it to be near the top/Vcc side.

Comment: 5V is most likely fine. I've only seen datasheets for IR-receiver  that  accept a voltage of  5V or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solved your problem.

You said

> I checked the LED with a multimeter and indeed it is a visible bicolor
>   LED, so there is no IR blaster in this board.

So, be kind, accept this answer so we can close your question.

I'm posting, not comment, only to get this out of the "unanswered".